# Trouble resizing partitions on Windows 7 Enterprise disc

Tags: windows-7, linux, partitioning

I have an HP EliteBook with Windows 7E. It was given to me by a company I worked for as a contractor a few years ago, and they don't seem to want it back. They're across the country, I guess they don't want to bother shipping it.

I normally use linux, and I want to shrink the Windows partition so I can add linux for dual-booting. Problem is, every tool I've used can only see the windows partitions, not alter them. Bitlocker is installed on the system, and though under my own user account, bitlocker says it is inactive, I'm thinking on a wider level, it must be active, hence preventing any changes to the partitions.

I can access my own user account without problem, but I don't have the bitlocker key, or the main admin password.

Under these circumstances, can anyone think of a way to resize the windows partition?

Or is the only option to wipe the disk with something like dd, and install just linux?

I was hoping to keep windows, because I have two scanners that I've never been able to get running under linux, despite hours of trying. But maybe windows will have to go?

Thanks.

Comment: One option I can think of is to copy track-to-track to a larger disc, then install Linux in the free space. If the laptop is old, a larger disc will not be expensive, cheaper than a Windows licence. There is another option, but I'm not sure of its legality, so I'll keep it to myself for now.

Answer (score 1):

It depends if the Windows partition is Primary or Secondary. Primary partitions can only be extended (they CANNOT be shrinked). You can do almost anything with Secondary partitions. Also: almost all of the 3rd-party partition programs out there won't work. Why they wont work? *I'll give you and example:* If you launch a Partition program on a loaded Windows PC/laptop its going to show you only the partitions that are visible for this operation system (unless you gave the needed permissions for the partition program)

So my suggest is you try the **Hiren's Boot CD**, which can be found over [here](http://www.hirensbootcd.org/)

It can also be loaded from an USB thumb drive, since CD's are not something everyone has in their house - [link here.](https://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd-on-usb-disk)

So there is a tool, called *Gparted Partition Wizard* that's going to show **ALL** of your partitions on your hard drives (it doesn't matter how much HDD's or SSD's you have) so from that point you can extend,shrink,rename,format and etc.

if you find this answer helpful you can mark it as an Answer. Thank you and good luck Dave!

Comment: Love Hirens Boot CD - good answer.

Comment: I already tried gparted, and it won't let me do anything to the partitions, other than see them. It won't even let me reformat them.

Comment: Thank you @leinad13 !

Dave, you can only see the partitions? What happens when you try to format some drive for example? Any errors?
*ALSO*: My brother just told me, that he used **Acronis Disk Director** long time ago for a situation just like yours.

Comment: Maybe the laptop has some kind of hardware raid solution? I've seen issues with partitions when using a hardware RAID solution, even some laptops have these now.